# Execution plan changed for existing query - high CPU usage

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.7

So few weeks ago we had an alert on our production MySQL database due to a CPU usage spike. We identified the issue as a query that had been there for several months that suddenly was misbehaving. The execution plan of that query is:

```
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys                                            | key                        | key_len | ref                        | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                     | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                       | 2485 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | c          | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY                                                  | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                       | 7420 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | app        | NULL       | ref  | applications_status_ix,applications_ibfk_3               | applications_ibfk_3        | 4       | prod_v3.c.id               |  750 |     0.41 | Using where                                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | inv        | NULL       | ref  | app_id                                                   | app_id                     | 4       | ref.app.app_id             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

What we did was to add an index hint to use `applications_status_ix` and then the query performance went back to normal and the CPU usage went down:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                 | key                           | key_len | ref                        | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL                          | NULL    | NULL                       |   5077 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | app        | NULL       | range  | applications_status_ix        | applications_status_ix        | 1       | NULL                       | 464405 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY                       | 4       | app.company_id             |      1 |    10.00 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | inv        | NULL       | ref    | app_id                        | app_id                        | 4       | app_id                     |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically on the query we want certain application status that have a minimum appearance on the table. That's why is better using that index even with this cardinality:

```
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| applications        |          1 | applications_status_ix          |            1 | status            | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| applications        |          1 | applications_ibfk_3             |            1 | company_id        | A         |       16240 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why would the query planner suddenly decided use a different execution plan on a query that has been in use for a while? I do not have hard proof, but I really doubt the cardinality changed materially from what we have now.
2. Trying to find a solution we found a about [Histograms](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/histogram-statistics-in-mysql/) (values distribution is called on other DBMS). But unfortunately they are only available on MySQL 8 and we are still using version 5.7. Do you happen to know any other workaround on our MySQL versions?

EDIT1:

So the query being executed is

```
SELECT sum((CASE
                WHEN `alias_50656806`.`status` = 'CAPTURED' THEN `alias_50656806`.`amount`
                ELSE `alias_50656806`.`due_by` END - `alias_50656806`.`recovered_amount`))
FROM (SELECT `app`.`app_id`,
             `app`.`status`,
             `app`.`amount`,
             `app`.`purchases`,
             `app`.`due_by`,
             sum(CASE
                     WHEN (`inv`.`paid_at` IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(current_date(), `inv`.`created_at`) < 10) THEN 0
                     ELSE IFNULL(`inv`.`amount_due`, 0) END) AS `recovered_amount`
      FROM `applications` AS `app`
               JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `app`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`
               LEFT OUTER JOIN `application_invoices` AS `inv` USING (`app_id`)
      WHERE (NOT (`app`.`repurchases`) AND
             `app`.`status` IN ('CAPTURED', 'LOCKED', 'ERROR') AND `c`.`is_test` = FALSE AND 1 = 1)
      GROUP BY `app`.`credit_app_id`, `app`.`status`, `app`.`credit_amount`, `app`.`cashless_repurchases`,
               `app`.`due_by`) AS `alias_50656806`;
```

An the table sizes are:

- applications has 12701431 records.
- companies has 7500 records
- the status distributions is

```
STATUS          COUNT (*)
RECOVER_FUNDS   46400
ERROR           18792
LOCKED          3
CAPTURED        151854
```

And applications table DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `app_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `updated_at` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `status` enum('PREAPPROVED','INCOMPLETE','DENIED','PENDING_DATA','PENDING_CC','FAILED_DATA','ERROR','READY','CAPTURED','EXPIRED','SETTLED','LOCKED','OPTED_OUT','RECOVER_FUNDS','EXCLUDED','ABANDONED','BAD_OPT') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `account_code` enum('REF','NO_REF') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `flow_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `app_ext_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `cashless_repurchases` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `random_no` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.5',
  `breakage_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_repurch` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_repurch` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `repurch_count` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_repurch_amount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `due_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `due_by_customer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `flow_id` (`flow_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `app_ext_id` (`app_ext_id`),
  KEY `applications_customer_ix` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `applications_status_ix` (`status`),
  KEY `applications_ibfk_3` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`flow_id`) REFERENCES `flow_entries` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `applications_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `application_statuses` (`status`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12709869 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: _Please_ provide the `SELECT` statement _and_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Also, give some hints as to the sizes of the tables.  There are many _possible_ answers to your question; those details are needed to help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: SHOW INDEX FROM table_name; will update your statistics and display cardinality by column when finished.  Please post these results as well for each table involved.  Test your query again, the SHOW INDEX FROM table_name; may improve your response time.

Comment: Rick I have added mos of the information you requested (I have not added companies table DDL because that would make this question even longer). Wilson the index cardinality is obtained using SHOW INDEX FROM. I removed some of the cardinalities trying to simplify.

Comment: Am I correct in estimating that the `WHERE` clause filters out rare things, thereby keeping over 98% of the rows?

Comment: Yes, as you can see on they counts the whole table is 12.701.431 but the records which the required status are 170K .

Comment: It may work better to pull the `c` references out.  Move them to the outer layer or perhaps make another `SELECT` layer just to exclude (or include) the "test" companies.

Comment: It is rarely useful to have an index on a low-cardinality column (eg, `status`).

Answer (score 0):

The values in `filtered` column in both execution plans look pretty off target. Maybe it would help to disable `condition_fanout_filter` optimizer switch in the session executing these multi-join queries (see more about [condition filtering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/condition-filtering.html)).

> Why would the query planner suddenly decided use a different execution plan on a query that has been in use for a while? I do not have hard proof, but I really doubt the cardinality changed ...

It probably takes the growing `applications` table size into account even if the number of records to select is mostly constant. Maybe an optimizer switch to make it prefer larger tables as leading would help to reduce the probability of similar failures in other queries (somewhat like Oracle's `DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT`). But I don't see any such feature in MySQL.

> Do you happen to know any other workaround

Query optimizer is somehow able to estimate the number of selected rows in `applications` : 464405 . But that's at least twice as more as the actual count from "table sizes" section. Maybe just `ANALYZE TABLE applications` may help to reduce the estimate and get the better execution plan without hints?

Comment: Thanks ichalov. I'm still need to investigate your first two points but I but just to let you know that the first thing I tried before even posting this question was to run the analyze and it did not work out :-). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would the query planner suddenly decided use a different execution plan on a query that has been in use for a while?

Change in data sizes or patterns - as things grow you can go over set limit (or a ratio between cardinalities between two objects) that causes a plan to look worse. This is why it can be important to test with realistic data sizes (including expected growth over some years, plus a bit in case things grow faster) during QA and even in dev environments.

If you look at your forced index plan, it expects to need to touch nearly half a million rows instead of the ten-thousand-ish for the other plan. I'm not sure why it would flip now and not sooner, perhaps there was a middle-ground plan it was using before (if you have a backup from before the issue became apparent, you could perhaps restore to another DB/server to check that).

> the status distributions is...

That is a lot less in total than the ~12.7Mrows in the table. Are there other values you've filtered from that list, or are the rest of the rows NULL in that column?

> Do you happen to know any other workaround on our MySQL versions?

Not specific for that version (this can be true non-mysql DBs too, even): it will only be able to use one index per object, and in this query you are joining on `company_id` and filtering on `status` & others. In such circumstances a compound index (i.e. on `company_id, status`, and perhaps the others you are filtering on to avoid extra lookups so `company_id, status, repurchases, is_test`) can help a lot at the expense of a little disk space & memory due to the larger index.

In other DBs (MS SQL Server, Prosgres, ...) you can reduce the space hit by removing any index you have on just `company_id` and the compound index will be used instead (assuming company_id is the first column in the compound key) where that would be needed, but that is not an option with mysql as this is implicitly created by the existence of the FK.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but need formatting to present a problem.)

```
 CASE WHEN `alias_50656806`.`status` = 'CAPTURED'
      THEN `alias_50656806`.`amount`
      ELSE `alias_50656806`.`due_by`
 END
```

"amount" sounds like money or a quantity; "due_by" sounds like a date.  But the result of this if-then-else is fed to a `SUM()`.  Summing due_by values does not make sense to me.